# LED lights in bathroom

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

[image]

I have a problem in my bathroom with a switch and LED lights in the roof (6 of them).
The switch is double; the right switch is for LED lights in the roof with a dimmer and the left one is for a mirror light, also LED. 
So, just by themselves, the LED lights in the roof turn off after few minutes (random time) after many, many years of working, and after that it was again turned on manually by the switcher and the LED lights in roof were just shining very faint (like when they are on the lowest level with the dimmer). 
I took one LED light in the roof out, and also a transformator of that LED. 
I checked the connections, checked the input in a 230V transformator, checked the output (it was something small, I don't remember exactly - 10, 12 or 24).
I took off the switch and saw everything was connected in the right way:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What country is this in?
What electronic stores are you familiar with?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the connection to the switch is broken and it is returning to what it thinks is the previously set dimming level?

[image]

Or maybe the overheating or short-circuit protection in the LED-driver is activating and turning off the outputs.

[image]

The correct wiring is as shown below

[image]

Note that the "switch-dim" connection should be connected to a momentary pushbutton switch - not to an external dimmer and not to a normal two-position lightswitch.

Comment: I was connected now without dimmer, and it is working good about switch and lamps with transformator, but it is just on half prosent of the power. ( lights are shining only half prosent of power), what i must to do it?

Comment: @toni_b: I'm not sure what you mean by "connected without dimmer" - are you using an external dimmer-switch? - The HE2020 is not designed for that. I would buy and install a 230V AC rated momentary push-button switch. See updated answer. To get light level to max, you need to use a switch to connect live to the connector labelled "switch-dim" for several seconds then disconnect (release push-button or turn off toggle switch)

Comment: It was working many years ago, so conections are good, somethink is burned or new problem with parts who break down after some time, like switch or transformator..

Comment: I was conected on switch L and L wire from swicher to transformator. And of course there is N, switch is working coreect, as transformator, input are 230v. And output os 75V*

Comment: My question is, can i now buy stadard transformator 230V to 75V (without dimmer), and conect that transformator.. and i will have then normal switcher for these led light?

Comment: @toni_b: The HE2020 isn't simply a standard 230V to 75V AC transformer, it is a 350 mA constant-current LED-driver - these are very different things and not usually interchangeable. You very likely need something that rectifies AC to DC and provides a constant-current of 350 mA.